# UDP Socket Client in .NET

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, client

I use UDP Sokckts in my client application.
Here are some code snippets:

```
SendIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);
ReceiveIP = (EndPoint)(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0));
socket = new Socket(
    AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Dgram,
    ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.Bind(ReceiveIP);
```

And to Receive (while(true)):

```
byte[] data = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];
int receivedDataLength = socket.ReceiveFrom(data, ref ReceiveIP);
string s= Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength);
```

I am doing an infinite while on the receive, there are other things to be done in the while, even if nothing is received.. I want to check if there are actually available data then receive else do not wait. Note the current receive method waits until the server sends a message.

Comment: Please edit your question to have a question in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `socket.Available()` to determine if there is any waiting data before calling `ReceiveFrom()`. Ideally, though, you should consider farming out input handling to other threads using `BeginReceiveFrom()` and its asynchronous friends.